# Micro XRCE-DDS agent installation error in PX4 tutorial

Tags: ros-humble, packages, px4

I am trying to run the following code from the [PX4 ROS2 User Guide](https://docs.px4.io/main/en/ros/ros2_comm.html#setup-micro-xrce-dds-agent-client):

```
git clone https://github.com/eProsima/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent.git
cd Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib/
```

but whenever I try to run `make` I get this error:

```
loading initial cache file /home/micha/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/build/uagent-prefix/tmp/uagent-cache-.cmake
-- Setting build type to 'Release' as none was specified.
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (tinyxml2)
  does not match the name of the calling package (TinyXML2).  This can lead
  to problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/FindTinyXML2.cmake:40 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  build/temp_install/fastrtps-2.14/share/fastrtps/cmake/fastrtps-config.cmake:51 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:153 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found tinyxml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml2.so
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found version "3.0.2")
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:247 (add_library):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target microxrcedds_agent
  because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libssl.so.3] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/micha/miniforge3/lib
    runtime library [libcrypto.so.3] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/micha/miniforge3/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/micha/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/build
[ 94%] Performing build step for 'uagent'
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/microxrcedds_agent.dir/src/cpp/Agent.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/spdlog/spdlog.h:12,
                 from /home/micha/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/include/uxr/agent/logger/Logger.hpp:23,
                 from /home/micha/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/include/uxr/agent/client/session/stream/OutputStream.hpp:22,
                 from /home/micha/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/include/uxr/agent/client/session/Session.hpp:20,
                 from /home/micha/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/include/uxr/agent/client/ProxyClient.hpp:20,
                 from /home/micha/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/include/uxr/agent/Root.hpp:18,
                 from /home/micha/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/src/cpp/Agent.cpp:16:
/usr/include/spdlog/common.h:127:111: error: ‘basic_runtime’ is not a member of ‘fmt’
  127 | alue || std::is_same<remove_cvref_t<T>, fmt::basic_runtime<Char>>::value>
      |                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/include/spdlog/common.h:127:111: error: ‘basic_runtime’ is not a member of ‘fmt’
/usr/include/spdlog/common.h:127:125: error: template argument 2 is invalid
  127 | s_same<remove_cvref_t<T>, fmt::basic_runtime<Char>>::value>
      |                                              ^~~~

/usr/include/spdlog/common.h:127:138: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘>’ token
  127 | ame<remove_cvref_t<T>, fmt::basic_runtime<Char>>::value>
      |                                                        ^

make[5]: *** [CMakeFiles/microxrcedds_agent.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/microxrcedds_agent.dir/src/cpp/Agent.cpp.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/microxrcedds_agent.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/uagent.dir/build.make:86: uagent-prefix/src/uagent-stamp/uagent-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:169: CMakeFiles/uagent.dir/all] Error 2
```

I think the error may be with the version of the `spdlog` library. I tried upgrading the library to 1.13.0 but it did not fix the issue.

I'm not very experienced with ROS so I'm a little lost on how I should go about fixing this. I am also using Humble.

Comment: You say that you upgraded `spdlog` to 1.13.0, but what version were you suing initially? What version of `libfmt` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem isn't exactly the version of `spdlog`, but rather you need a newer version of `libfmt`, or at least a version that is compatible with which ever version of `spdlog` that you choose to use.

Basically, it is a versioning incompatibility issue between `spdlog` and `libfmt`.

See other examples:

- [1.9.1 and 1.9.2 fail to build with fmt 7.1.3 #2050](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/issues/2050)
- [Bug 810496 - dev-libs/spdlog-1.9.2: incompatible with dev-libs/libfmt-7 (spdlog/common.h:127:111: error: ‘basic_runtime’ is not a member of ‘fmt’)](https://bugs.gentoo.org/810496)

You don't seem to state which version of `libfmt` you are using, but that isn't all that important, to this answer. You will just need to play around with the versions until you find a pair of versions that *are* compatible.

##### Compatible versions

FWIW, from [Including fmt and spdlog in a project #728](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/issues/728):

> spdlog 1.8.0 and above are bundled fmt version 7.0.3

From [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76581574/spdlog-fmt-version-conflict#comment135024595_76581574) under [spdlog & fmt version conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76581574/4424636)

> The spdlog project is very explicit about which fmt version should be used. For instance, 1.11.0 requires fmt/9.1.0 (see [github.com/gabime/spdlog/releases/tag/v1.11](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/releases/tag/v1.11)). For Conan, when you include same package twice, but with different versions, is a conflict, and the user should fix. There are several ways to fix it (see [docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/versioning/…](https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/versioning/conflicts.html#resolving-conflicts)) but for your specific case, better keeping fmt/9.1.0 version only, as spdlog will not work with fmt 10.x. You can use version range to avoid problems, like `fmt/[<=10.0.0]`

From [Bug 810496 - dev-libs/spdlog-1.9.2: incompatible with dev-libs/libfmt-7 (spdlog/common.h:127:111: error: ‘basic_runtime’ is not a member of ‘fmt’)](https://bugs.gentoo.org/810496)

> Try either stable spdlog or use ~testing ~libfmt-8.0.1
>
> Looks like it's no longer compatible with stable libfmt-7

---

In summary:

- spdlog 1.8.0 and above are bundled fmt version 7.0.3
- spdlog 1.92 requires fmt 8.0.1
- spdlog 1.11.0 requires fmt 9.1.0
- spdlog 1.13.0 requires fmt v???

  - Refer to [spdlog not adaptable with newer versions of fmt #3007](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/issues/3007). This *may* be the issue that you are seeing with spdlog v1.13.0 = as issue #3007 deals with the latest release (at the time of writing) which *is* v1.13.0